# Analyse the logical form of the following statements

Tags: logic

I am not completely sure about the request of this question:

```
Analyze the logical form of the following statements using variables
```

1. C and PASCAL are programming languages, either C is better than
   PASCAL or PASCAL is better than C.

Should we simply write the statements? There's no conclusion and it seems too trivial, in fact it's the first exercise, but I am not sure anyways.

I could answer with:

L(C) `% C is a programming language`

L(P) `% Pascal is a programming language`

L(C) $ \land $ L(P) `%C and Pascal are programming languages`

B(C, P) $ \lor $ B(P, C) `% C is better than Pascal or Pascal is better than C`

Comment: It looks fine ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your formalization and argument look perfectly fine. Keep your good work!